# Square aspect ratio in 2D plots for static export

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to create 2D scatter plots in plotly.py and export them as static .svg-files with a square aspect ratio. More specifically, I want to make the axis square in screen units (similar to this matplotlib question: [Matplotlib scale axis lengths to be equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057591/matplotlib-scale-axis-lengths-to-be-equal)).
Is there any way of achieving something similar using plotly? (Note that my x and y data are on a different scale)

I already tried to simply set the figure width and height to equal values, which works more or less fine if I have only one trace and no legend.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=np.random.uniform(0, 1, 50), 
    y=np.random.randint(1, 100, 50), 
    mode='markers',
    ))


fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)

# NOTE: Static image generation in plotly requires Kaleido (pip install -U kaleido)
fig.write_image("example.svg")
```

[Output: example plot with one trace and fixed width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YP2M.png)

However, if I have mutliple traces and add a legend, I end up with a distorted plot:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=np.random.uniform(0, 1, 50), 
    y=np.random.randint(1, 100, 50), 
    mode='markers',
    name="SomeLongTraceLabel1"
    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=np.random.uniform(0, 1, 50), 
    y=np.random.randint(1, 100, 50), 
    mode='markers',
    name="SomeLongTraceLabel2"
    ))

fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)

# NOTE: Static image generation requires Kaleido (pip install -U kaleido)
fig.write_image("example.svg")
```

[Output: example plot with two traces and a legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoMZK.png)

I think it is possible to achieve this for 3D plots via the `layout.scene.aspectmode="cubic"` setting, but I could find a similar setting for 2D plots.
Is there any way to make my plots automatically look like this: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQfCG.png) without readjusting the figure width/height everytime with regard to the length of my legend items ?

Comment: There is [content](https://community.plotly.com/t/image-export-how-to-set-dpi-alternatively-how-to-scale-down-using-width-and-height/49536) in the plotly community that can help you with your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, in this thread the solution is also to set the width/height of the figure (even though it is done while saving), meaning that it does not solve my problem of retaining a square plot regardless of whether a legend is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem... after seeing this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/70

I solved it as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Z')
fig.update_xaxes(constrain='domain')  
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor= 'x')
```

Not sure if it will work for mulitple traces and legends.